# Is there an easy way to exclude classes from test coverage using Java Annotations in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, gradle, kotlin

I have a (gradle + kotlin) spring boot project with several DTOs, configuration classes, constants etc. that I don't want to be analyzed during test coverage analysis.

Is there a convenient Java notation that I can use?

Comment: [@ignore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)?

Comment: Which code coverage tool?

Comment: It would be the default that comes with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test`. Not sure how I can dig into this package further in IntelliJ

Comment: @ignore doesn't seem to work for me :/

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-test` does not provide anything for measuring code coverage. Perhaps you're using IntelliJ's built-in coverage support?

Comment: ah potentially... that's not good. Won't work in a CI/CD pipeline. Probably need to look at using a separate package :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me. Had to write some custom custom filtering logic in a very hacky sort of way, but it did the job.

Upvoting @Min Hyoung Hong's answer for leading me down the right track.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile<KotlinJvmOptions>> {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    withType<JacocoReport> {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = false
            csv.isEnabled = false
            html.destination = file("$buildDir/jacocoHtml")
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            val filesToAvoidForCoverage = listOf(
                    "/dto",
                    "/config",
                    "MyApplicationKt.class"
            )
            val filesToCover = mutableListOf<String>()
            File("build/classes/kotlin/main/app/example/core/")
                    .walkTopDown()
                    .mapNotNull { file ->
                        var match = false
                        filesToAvoidForCoverage.forEach {
                            if (file.absolutePath.contains(it)) {
                                match = true
                            }
                        }
                        return@mapNotNull if (!match) {
                            file.absolutePath
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                    }
                    .filter { it.contains(".class") }
                    .toCollection(filesToCover)

            classDirectories = files(filesToCover)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said that you are using kotlin and gradle. So I assume that you are using jacoco for test coverage.

This is one of the jacoco coverage excludes example.

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/*Application**'])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey bro this didn't quite do it for me, but it did lead me down the right track so I'm upvoting your answer :)